# Longest word accepted by DFA

Tags: automata, finite-automata

The length of the longest word that can be accepted by any DFA which satisfies the following two
properties is

I) It has $4$ states.

II)It does not accept any word of length $8$ or $9$ or $10$ or $11$ or $12$?

Comment: This is a very nice problem that I think you should try to solve on your own.

Comment: Bonus question: "8 to 12" can easily be replaced by "8 to 11" (or "9 to 12"). But can one replace it with even smaller set?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- If the automaton has only 4 states, then some state has to be revisited at most every 4 parsed letters.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Actually I thought about this but could not agree upon final and non final states.. which states should I take as non final state is still bugging me.. let me try